# Search box and submit button not aligned in CSS

Tags: html, css, search, wordpress-theming

I added a search box to my wordpress website but since there are a lot of default styles in wordpress I can't seem to manage to get bot the box and the submit button aligned.

Currently the submit button is starting a little higher than my search box, though I haven't specified any margin or padding for my button..

The website is online here; http://sennheiser-apart.com

And these are the css lines I currently have for the search things in my child theme's css file.

```
button {
    border:none;
    padding:6px;
}

input {
    height:28px;
    border:none;
}

input[type="submit"]{
    border:none;
    background-color:#00AFDD;
    height:28px;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:18px;
    margin:0px;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover{
    background-color:#ADAFB2;
}
```

Even searching on my page and looking for a line of styling in other files that wordpress uses doesn't help, I just can't find what's causing this. Does anyone have a clue? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without looking too much into detail, you can add this to the `<form>`-element:

```
padding: 5px 0 0 0;
```

and to both `<input>`-elements add:

```
vertical-align: top;
```

This should do the trick.